# How to update my view with jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC 4 with razor view. What I want to do is to add a new instance of my div class in the view. What do I need to have in my jquery?

This is the div.

```
<input type="button" id="btAdd" value="Add Answer"/>
 <div class="AnswerLabel">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.answer.AnswerText, new {id = "AnswerLabelField"})
    </div>
    <div class="AnswerEditor">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.answer.AnswerText, new {id = "AnswerEditorField"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.answer.AnswerText)
    </div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#btAdd').click(function () {
    //what do i need here;
    return false;
});
```

});

Comment: Which div are you trying to add? `AnswerEditor`?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

Use `.append(.html())`

```
$('body').append($('.AnswerEditor').html());
```

Comment: As I understood it he wanted to add another instance of the `AnswerEditor` div. My answer is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Frayt: Tiny code snippets are better as comments. It looks like the right code; explain a little on what it does and you'll be good.

Comment: Worked perfect for me thank you. Do you have any idea how this code would look like in pure cshtml code or code behind ?

Comment: I don't understand the question Vladimir. The code above would have to go in either a javascript file with a `.js` extension or within `<script>` tags in HTML

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" id="btAdd" value="Add Answer"/>
<div id="attach">
 <div class="AnswerLabel">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.answer.AnswerText, new {id = "AnswerLabelField"})
    </div>
    <div class="AnswerEditor">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.answer.AnswerText, new {id = "AnswerEditorField"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.answer.AnswerText)
    </div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function () {
$('#btAdd').click(function () {
    $('#attach').append('html content here');
    return false;
});

});
```